# condition not getting satisfied in js in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an MVC application. I have written some js for comparing two values in a dropdown. Even though the values are the same the condition is not getting satisfied and skipping the code block.

What's the wrong with the code below?

```
 $('#frmCreate').unbind('submit').submit(function (e) {
            var CompanyID1 =  $('#CompanyId').val()
            var TransferedCompanyId1 =  $('#TransferedCompanyId').val()

            If ($('#CompanyId').val() !=  $('#TransferedCompanyId').val())
            {
                alert(CompanyID1);
                alert(TransferedCompanyId1);
                $(".SameCompanyValidation").text("Both Companies should not be same.");
                e.preventDefault()
            }

        });
```

> Solved...Thanks to [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) have to use if instead of If

```
   if ($('#CompanyId').val() !=  $('#TransferedCompanyId').val())
```

Comment: Should your `if` not be lower case?

Comment: **"Even though the values are the same"** then why the condition is `!=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the wrong with the code below?

Don't forget that javascript is a case sensitive language and `If` is not the same as `if`:

```
if ($('#CompanyId').val() != $('#TransferedCompanyId').val())
```

Comment: Knew I should have put that as an answer instead of a comment :)